# Angular 8 with Springboot : issue when dowload any type of file from server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file, server, download

I have my REST API where I put the name and the extension, I want my angular app to download on click via my web browser when i choose one of file that i seclect but I got HttpErrorResponse :

[image: isue]

This is my REST API :

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFileFromLocal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            String fileName, String extension) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(cmsPath +"/"+ fileName+"."+ extension);
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        if (file.exists()) {

            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {
                //unknown mimetype so set the mimetype to application/octet-stream
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            response.setContentType(mimeType);

        
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""));

            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());         
                try {
                    FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(file.length())
                .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
        
    }
```

This is my service on Angular app :

```
public downloadFile(fileName: String, extension: String): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(
      environment.ws.url + this.urlService + this.urlDownloadFile + "/" + fileName + "/" + extension, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem(this.ACCESS_TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY),
        responseType: 'blob'
      }),

    });
  }
```

And Invocation :

```
public downloadFile(element: FileElement): void {
    this.cmsService.downloadFile(element.name, element.extension).subscribe((resultBlob: Blob) => {
      var downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(resultBlob);
      window.open(downloadURL);
    });
    ;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On you subscribe use as params

```
   return this._http.get<any>(`${this.route}/endpoint/${id}`,
  { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
```

if you usign response entity better return something like this

```
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadpdf(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(ConstanteUtils.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/pdf")
        .header(ConstanteUtils.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=yourfile.pdf")
        .body(service.reportPDF(id));
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i would like to be able to download any type of file, not only pdf file